# On dummy variable

Tags: econometrics

I am doing a study on determinants of livelihood diversification by using censored Tobit regression model .if I include more than one dummy variable along with quantitative variable,will it cause any problem?

Comment: What kind of problems are you concerned about potentially?

Answer (score 0):

No. Unless these extra dummies introduce colinearity issues and are poorly informed (ie very small number of events)